# What is this kind of URL called?

Tags: http, url

```
http://admin:123456@192.168.1.178/videostream.cgi
```

I didn't know that username and password could be set directly in the URL. How does this work? Is it standard? What search terms should I use to find out more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a standard way of providing login credentials in the URL so it doesn't have to prompt you for them.

`admin` is the username, `123456` is the password. The hostname is `192.168.1.178` as usual. You're connecting through the `http` protocol, so HTTP authentication is used here to access the script.

Comment: BTW, do you know how to configure HTTP authentication in apache ?

Comment: Is it safe? For example, can I save a bookmark to access a `phpMyAdmin` with the user/password on the url like that?

Comment: @BrunoLM: no, it isn't, and I don't think that's its intended use. It can be useful when providing URI-based connection strings instead, for example.

Comment: @Alan: I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Comment: IIRC this kind of automatic authentication was discontinued from IE7 onwards because it was percieved to be a big security risk, and at the time IE was pretty much the only browser that supported it.

Answer (score 3):

It's the authority part of a URI scheme defined by RFC3986.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2

Answer (score 1):

It's just a normal URL. See here for the URL syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax